# How can I test if a filename matching a pattern exists in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, match, exists, glob

Can I do something like this in Perl? Meaning pattern match on a file name and check whether it exists.

```
    if(-e "*.file")
    {
      #Do something
    }
```

I know the longer solution of asking system to list the files present; read it as a file and then infer whether file exists or not.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [`glob`](http://p3rl.org/glob) to return an array of all files matching the pattern:

```
@files = glob("*.file");

foreach (@files) {
    # do something
}
```

If you simply want to know whether a file matching the pattern exists, you can skip the assignment:

```
if (glob("*.file")) {
    # At least one file matches "*.file"
}
```

Comment: Just to be complete, you can do `foreach (glob("*.file")) { something }` as well...

Comment: But I am unable to put regexp in there. Can I use regular expressions ?

Comment: @alertjean No, you'll have to open the directory and manually scan file names using a regular expression. `glob` only supports the traditional [shell wild cards](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/wildcards.html).

Comment: @Jean You can grep after the glob, e.g. `grep /g/, glob "*.txt"` will give you all the .txt files that have a 'g' in the name.

Comment: fwiw, [`glob`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) docs say: _”If non-empty braces are the only wildcard characters used in the glob, no filenames are matched, but potentially many strings are returned.“_ — so this solution only works if wildcards are present. too bad.

Comment: I think one should force a list context in the `if` variant, because `glob` behaves differently in a scalar context. Docs of [`scalar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) state that you can force list context using `@{[ (some expression) ]}`, so the condition would be `if (@{[ glob("*.file") ]}) {}`.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows I had to use [File::Glob::Windows](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwids6COiKjcAhWDX5QKHSNmBrUQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmetacpan.org%2Fpod%2FFile%3A%3AGlob%3A%3AWindows&usg=AOvVaw2JUfuR71j6W_dVgOXcujHB) as the Windows path separating backslashes don't seem to work perl's glob.

Answer (score 0):

On *nix systems, I've used the following with good results.

```
sub filesExist { return scalar ( my @x = `ls -1a 2> /dev/null "$_[0]"` ) }
```

It replies with the number of matches found, or 0 if none.  Making it easily used in 'if' conditionals like:

```
if( !filesExist( "/foo/var/not*there.log" ) &&
    !filesExist( "/foo/var/*/*.log" ) &&
    !filesExist( "/foo/?ar/notthereeither.log" ) )
{
    print "No matches!\n";
} else {
    print "Matches found!\n";
}
```

Exactly what patterns you could use would be determined by what your shell supports.  But most shells support the use of '*' and '?' - and they mean the same thing everywhere I've seen.  Of course, if you removed the call to the 'scalar' function, it would return the matches - useful for finding those variable file names.

Comment: It's always better to avoid calling out to the shell like that, because first you might not always be running on the kind of system you tested on, and second there might easily be cases where someone has a nonstandard binary or environment variables affecting the functionality. Related, if you the `$LESS` env-var, then `man` is affected by the options in it.